Crear un método para añadir elementos a un Array
package Ejercicio2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrrayDePisos extends Piso {

    private Piso losPisos[];

    public ArrrayDePisos(String tipoCasa, double metrosCuadrados, double precio, String ubicacion, int numPiso, Piso[] losPisos) {
        super(tipoCasa, metrosCuadrados, precio, ubicacion, numPiso);
        this.losPisos = losPisos;
    }

    public void mostrarPisos() {
        for (Piso piso : losPisos) {
            System.out.println(piso);
        }
    }

    public void calcularPrecio() {
        double suma = 0;
        for (Piso piso : losPisos){
            suma += piso.getPrecio();
        }
    }

    public ArrrayDePisos anadirPiso(ArrrayDePisos piso){
        return piso.add;

    }
/*Aquí, en este método es donde quiero usarlo para añadir cosas a un Array y no se como exactamente. Gracias*/


}


veo que haces uso del array los pisos[] pero estas importando la libreria ArrayList,entender  la diferencia de un array y un arrayList te ayudaria a resolver tu duda

Estas mezclando tu objeto con su controlador, te sugiero separar en 2.

Objeto Piso.
Controlador de Piso.

CLASE PISO:
public class Piso {
    // Atributos
    private String tipoCasa;
    private double metrosCuadrados;
    private double precio;
    private String ubicacion;
    private int numPiso;

    // Constructor
    public Piso(String tipoCasa, double metrosCuadrados, double precio, String ubicacion, int numPiso) {
        this.tipoCasa = tipoCasa;
        this.metrosCuadrados = metrosCuadrados;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
        this.numPiso = numPiso;
    }

    // Getters y Setters
    public String getTipoCasa() {
        return tipoCasa;
    }

    public void setTipoCasa(String tipoCasa) {
        this.tipoCasa = tipoCasa;
    }

    public double getMetrosCuadrados() {
        return metrosCuadrados;
    }

    public void setMetrosCuadrados(double metrosCuadrados) {
        this.metrosCuadrados = metrosCuadrados;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getUbicacion() {
        return ubicacion;
    }

    public void setUbicacion(String ubicacion) {
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
    }

    public int getNumPiso() {
        return numPiso;
    }

    public void setNumPiso(int numPiso) {
        this.numPiso = numPiso;
    }

    // Método toString para representación de cadena del objeto
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Piso{" +
                "tipoCasa='" + tipoCasa + '\'' +
                ", metrosCuadrados=" + metrosCuadrados +
                ", precio=" + precio +
                ", ubicacion='" + ubicacion + '\'' +
                ", numPiso=" + numPiso +
                '}';
    }
}

CONTROLADOR DE PISO:
public class ControladorPiso {
    private ArrayList<Piso> listaPisos;

    // Constructor
    public ControladorPiso() {
        listaPisos = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // Método para agregar un piso a la lista
    public void addPiso(Piso piso) {
        listaPisos.add(piso);
        System.out.println("Piso agregado correctamente.");
    }

    // Método para imprimir la información de todos los pisos
    public void printPisos() {
        if (listaPisos.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No hay pisos para mostrar.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Lista de pisos:");
            for (int i = 0; i < listaPisos.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Piso " + (i + 1) + ":");
                System.out.println(listaPisos.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}


Muchas gracias.
